# VBA Ctrl+S add date and time to current save directory

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a code that will activate upon a user pushing Ctrl+S on VBA.
I have created a workbook that uses macros so I need to overwrite the Ctrl+S function so that when a user saves the file it doesn't overwrite the previous workbook as the data in it will be lost.

so far I have:

```
Sub Save()

dim path as string
dim time as string
dim fname as string
time = format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")
path = application.thisworkbook.path
fname = path & "\Title" & time
thisworkbook.saveas filename:= fname, _
                    fileformat:=xlopenxmlworkbookmacroenabled

end sub
```

How do I make it so that this code replaces Ctrl+S to prevent people from accidentally running the macros then saving and overwriting potentially important data?
Is it possible to only have this Ctrl+S only apply to the workbook the code is written in?

My apologies if this has already been asked.

Comment: In Excel: Alt F8 > Options > set Ctrl S to the macro

Comment: Maybe consider using the  [BeforeSave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave) event.

Comment: Will assigning it to Ctrl+S effect other workbooks that may be open? or will it only overwrite it for the workbook the macro is in?

Comment: Couldn't you figure that out by testing it yourself?